# Json Status=0 not displaying

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm trying to show my json response after user login. It successfully displaying response in my app when user put correct info. But the app getting crashed when user putting wrong credentials
Here is my json response when user put wrong info. It should displaying Status=0 in my app display(or whatever response I want to display

```
I/flutter (16426): {"Status":"0","Message":"Wrong Password provided","UserData":null}
```

Here is my API call when user press the login button

```
 Future<void> login() async{
    var jsonResponse = null;
if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://jhhjhjhjhjhjhj"),
      body: ({
        'LoginId': emailController.text,
        'Password': passwordontroller.text
      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AfterLoginResPage(response: ApiResponse.fromJson(jsonResponse))));
  }

   else {
    print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    print(response.body);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid credentials")));
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Blank field is not allowed")));
}
```

}

My Model class

```
 class ApiResponse {
    ApiResponse({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.userData,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    UserData userData;

    factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ApiResponse(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        //userData: UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]),
        userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]), //======== Updated
    );


}

class UserData {
    UserData({
        required this.name,
        required this.encUserId,
    });

    String name;
    String encUserId;

    factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
        name: json["Name"],
        encUserId: json["EncUserId"],
    );

}
```

And then here I'm displaying my response which is successfully getting executed when User putting correct credentials. but got crashed when putting wrong credentials

```
 children: [
           Text("Status: ${widget.response.status}"),
           Text("Message: ${widget.response.message}"),
```

one more problem I'm facing ,here im able to display status and message What If I want to display `Name` & `EncUserId` also?.

here is my json response in postman after putting right info

```
{
"Status": "1",
"Message": "You are Logged in successfully",
"UserData": {
    "Name": "tuhinroy881@gmail.com",
    "EncUserId": "bbA/HajfPdswT0fhhiMvEg=="
}
```

}

.

Comment: Put all your build method, and what is the output of ```response.body``` after the wrong message?

Comment: Nothing wrong with response.body its printing in my console `I/flutter (16426): {"Status":"0","Message":"Wrong Password provided","UserData":null}`  which is correct, when Im putting wrong info in login. But my App getting crashed and its showing `NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]` was called on null. Receiver:null.Tried calling : []("Name") `

Comment: Replace ```userData: UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]),``` by ```userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]),```

Comment: its showing error `The argument type 'UserData?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserData'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

Comment: Can you please update the code now ?

Comment: Hey, just update the ` my Model class` code can you please check

Comment: Try ```userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]) as Map<String, dynamic>),```

Comment: No, still red error `The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserData'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

Comment: null safety is enabled?

Comment: yeah, I think so 2days ago I just updated all the SDK and all

Comment: Try ```UserData? userData;``` and ```userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"] as Map<String, dynamic>)```

Comment: The error is gone but the app still getting crashed if I put wrong login info :(

Comment: My bad! its working after Restart. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing , What if I want to display `Name` &  `EncUserId` ? because printing this way `Text("Status: ${widget.response.status}"),`  showing error

Comment: I need to see all your class to understand your structure, Ill post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since null safety is enabled, you need to change `UserData userData` to UserData? userData; and `userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"] as Map<String, dynamic>)`

Your problem is that you are trying to parse `UserData` while your error response doesn't have any `UserData` related information.

```
class ApiResponse {
    ApiResponse({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.userData,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    UserData? userData;

    factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ApiResponse(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]), 
    );


}
```